# Compare first 5 characters of consecutive lines - shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with following lines.

```
00070MICHAEL  
00071MARY  
00071JOHN  
00085ERIC  
00085PETER  
00097MICHAEL
```

I want to add a single character(#) at the end of each line whose first five characters are different from next lines' first five characters.

```
00070MICHAEL#  
00071MARY  
00071JOHN#  
00085ERIC  
00085PETER#  
00097MICHAEL#
```

How would do I this in shell scripting. A one-liner would be great.

I know this line adds a character(#) to every line,

```
awk '{$0=$0 "#"}1' filename
```

Thanks !

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We are not here to do your job for you. YOU write some code, we'll (maybe) help fix it.

Comment: Does the order in resulted file matter?

Comment: @Marc B. I have added a line of code. I do not know how to proceed after this.

Comment: that's like saying "here, I have a hammer. I've done my part, you build the rest of the skyscraper".

Comment: @Anatoly Yes it does. The same line order should be preserved.

Comment: @Marc B, I see most of the questions on this site answered this way. I don't understand how this question is different.

Comment: Why do you prefer a one-liner? For performance that might be better than a while loop, but a while loop is easier to understand/write. Something like a `cut -c1-5` and compare with remembered string, that way you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ curr = substr($0,1,5) }
NR>1 { printf "%s\n", (prev == curr ? "" : "#") }
{ printf "%s", $0; prev = curr }
END { print "#" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
00070MICHAEL#
00071MARY
00071JOHN#
00085ERIC
00085PETER#
00097MICHAEL#
```

You can, of course, cram it all onto a single line if you find that useful:

```
awk '{curr=substr($0,1,5)} NR>1{printf "%s\n",(prev==curr?"":"#")} {printf "%s",$0; prev=curr} END{print "#"}' file
```

Comment: Thanks Ed ! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'NR%2 {s=$0; next} {printf "%s", s;
        print (substr($0, 1, 5) == substr(s, 1, 5)) ? "" : "#"; print}' file
00070MICHAEL#
00071MARY
00071JOHN#
00085ERIC
00085PETER#
00097MICHAEL
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. But it does not work as expected. It adds the character  '#' for every two lines upon testing, irrespective of condition.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s*$/#/;N;/^(.....).*\n\1/s/#\n/\n/;P;D' file
```

Use the `-r` switch to remove some backslashes and make the regexp easier on the eye. Assume every line is different from the next and append a `#` to the end of the current line (also use this as an opportunity to remove whitespace at the end of lines as well). Append the next line and test it to see if it has the same five characters at its start as the previous line. If it does, remove the appended `#` and then print and delete the first line of the two lines in the pattern space. Repeat until all lines have been processed.